# How can I put a slice of a Matrix into a 3D Array with SMatrix type of inner structure?

Tags: julia

Suppose I have this Matrix:

```
julia> mat = [
       1 2 3 4
       5 6 7 8
       9 8 7 6
       ];
```

Then I want to put slices of this Matrix into a 3D `Array` with types of `SMatrix{Int64}`, like below:

```
julia> using StaticArrays

julia> arr = Array{SMatrix{Int64}, 3}(undef, 3, 2, 3);

julia> col_idx = [1, 2, 3];

julia> foreach(x->arr[:, :, x] = mat[:, x:x+1], col_idx)
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type
  Int64 to an object of type
  SMatrix{Int64}
Closest candidates are:
  convert(::Type{T}, ::LinearAlgebra.Factorization) where T<:AbstractArray at C:\Users\JUL\.julia\juliaup\julia-1.8.3+0.x64\share\julia\stdlib\v1.8\LinearAlgebra\src\factorization.jl:58
  convert(::Type{SA}, ::Tuple) where SA<:StaticArray at C:\Users\JUL\.julia\packages\StaticArrays\x7lS0\src\convert.jl:179
  convert(::Type{SA}, ::SA) where SA<:StaticArray at C:\Users\JUL\.julia\packages\StaticArrays\x7lS0\src\convert.jl:178
  ...
Stacktrace:
  [1] setindex!
    @ .\array.jl:968 [inlined]
  [2] macro expansion
    @ .\multidimensional.jl:946 [inlined]
  [3] macro expansion
    @ .\cartesian.jl:64 [inlined]
  [4] macro expansion
    @ .\multidimensional.jl:941 [inlined]
  [5] _unsafe_setindex!(::IndexLinear, ::Array{SMatrix{Int64}, 3}, ::Matrix{Int64}, ::Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}}, ::Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}}, ::Int64)
    @ Base .\multidimensional.jl:953
  [6] _setindex!
    @ .\multidimensional.jl:930 [inlined]
  [7] setindex!(::Array{SMatrix{Int64}, 3}, ::Matrix{Int64}, ::Function, ::Function, ::Int64)
    @ Base .\abstractarray.jl:1344
  [8] (::var"#5#6")(x::Int64)
    @ Main .\REPL[20]:1
  [9] foreach(f::var"#5#6", itr::Vector{Int64})
    @ Base .\abstractarray.jl:2774
 [10] top-level scope
    @ REPL[20]:1
```

How can I achieve it?

P.S.:
This is just a minimal and reproducible example. In the practical sense, I have a size of `(10, 10, 2000)` for `arr` and a big size for `mat` as well (`10x2000`, I guess)!

Comment: It's quite unclear what you want to do. Are you sure you don't want a regular `Array{Int, 3}`. You are trying to put regular integers there, so.. Also, `SMatrix{Int}` isn't properly specified. You must give the size too, or there's no point.

Comment: @DNF I want to do mathematical operations between each inner Matrix. So I decided to use SMatrix to gain speed. A Matrix is known as a 2D ndim object in Julia, so I didn't specify its size unless you want to say a different point (?). However, the `(undef, 3, 2, 3)` part of my code specifies the size clearly.

Comment: With `SMatrix` you specify its _size_ not just the number of dimensions. For example `SMatrix{3,4,Int}`, which is 2-dimensional with size 3x4. If you don't give the size, there's no point. There's no help in specifying the size afterwards, it must be in the type itself.

Comment: @DNF, Thanks! I didn't know it :(

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, do you want an Array of SMatrices?

```
mat = [ 1 2 3 4
        5 6 7 8
        9 8 7 6 ];

using StaticArrays

col_idx = [1, 2, 3];

arr = [SMatrix{3,2}(mat[:, x:x+1]) for x in col_idx]
3-element Vector{SMatrix{3, 2, Int64, 6}}:
 [1 2; 5 6; 9 8]
 [2 3; 6 7; 8 7]
 [3 4; 7 8; 7 6]
```

Comment: Yes, kind of. But I prefer a 3D Array object. Unless it can't be achieved, I should take your suggestion.

Comment: I got your point here. `SMatrix` objects are immutable.

Answer (score 1):

Then, what if I say:

```
julia> using StaticArrays

julia> mat = [
       1 2 3 4
       5 6 7 8
       9 8 7 6
       ];

julia> arr = Array{Int64, 3}(undef, 3, 2, 3);

julia> foreach(x->arr[:, :, x] = mat[:, x:x+1], [1, 2, 3]);

julia> sarr = SArray{Tuple{3, 2, 3}}(arr)
3×2×3 SArray{Tuple{3, 2, 3}, Int64, 3, 18} with indices SOneTo(3)×SOneTo(2)×SOneTo(3):
[:, :, 1] =
 1  2
 5  6
 9  8

[:, :, 2] =
 2  3
 6  7
 8  7

[:, :, 3] =
 3  4
 7  8
 7  6

julia> typeof(sarr[:, :, 1])
SMatrix{3, 2, Int64, 6} (alias for SArray{Tuple{3, 2}, Int64, 2, 6})
```

First, I created a regular 3D `Array`, then constructed a `SArray` based on it.
However, in the case of your practical situation, I tried the following:

```
julia> mat = rand(10, 2000);

julia> arr = Array{Float64, 3}(undef, 10, 2, 1999);

julia> foreach(x->arr[:, :, x] = mat[:, x:x+1], 1:1999);

julia> sarr = SArray{Tuple{10, 2, 1999}}(arr);
```

But it takes too much time to construct such a container. (I already canceled it, and I don't know the runtime of it.). Hence, in these cases, it's better to take [@AboAmmar's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74605145/20407495).

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @Shayan and @AboAmmar, this answer explores using `BlockArrays.jl` package to construct the desired result. `BlockArrays` puts existing arrays into a 'meta-array'. The sub-arrays can be of SMatrix type.

In code:

```
using StaticArrays, BlockArrays

mat = rand(10,2000)   # random demo matrix

# make all the slice SArrays
arr = [SArray{Tuple{10,2,1}, Float64, 3}(mat[:,i:i+1])
  for i=1:1999]
arr = reshape(arr,1,1,1999)

# glue them into a BlockArray
bricked = mortar(arr)
```

After now:

```
julia> size(bricked)
(10, 2, 1999)

julia> bricked[:,:,25]
1×1-blocked 10×2 BlockMatrix{Float64}:
 0.265972  0.258414 
 0.396142  0.863366 
 0.41708   0.648276 
 0.960283  0.773064 
 0.62513   0.268989 
 0.132796  0.0493077
 0.844674  0.791772 
 0.59638   0.0769661
 0.221536  0.388623 
 0.595742  0.50732
```

Hopefully this method gets the performance trade-off you wanted (or at least introduces some new ideas).